# Getting "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/system/people]..." when try to access jpa data via rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

This is the what I have for the repo:

`@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}`

http://localhost:8080/system/people is what I'm trying to access, where "http://localhost:8080/system" is the base url for the spring MVC project

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for it, according to the http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#getting-started.introduction, I added a class for the data access configuration:

`@Configuration
public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
        config.setBasePath("/api");
        return config;
    }
}`

In addition, I have also added `@Import(CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration.class)` in my spring applications config class. And now whenever I do a http://localhost:8080/system/api/people call, the database entries can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@RequestMapping(value="/people/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public interface PersonRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.